# Javascript cookie doesn't work on all page

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

Live site- http://chitrchatr.com

I successfully add setCookie function on exit button & another link. So, if anyone close popup or click on that link then cookie will be stored & popup never appears for him/her.

It works perfectly, i close/go to link it, it store cookie but when i try to go another page/link of website it appears again(cookie is already stored but it appers). Any idea how to fix it so it will never appears if anyone go to another page after storing cookie.

My HTML-

```
<div id="popupBox">
 <div id='popupContent' class='visiblebox' style='width:500px;height:446px;z-index:999999;left: 31%; top: 15%;'>
 <a onClick="document.getElementById('popupBox').style.display='none'; setCookie('abc', 'def', 1)" href='#' id='closebox' title='Close this box'>X</a>
.... 
PopUp content here
....
<a onClick="document.getElementById('popupBox').style.display='none'; setCookie('abc', 'def', 1)" href="http://chitrchatr.com/signup-and-win-new-smartphones-and-get-our-service-for-free/" target="_blank"><img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-1548" alt="Promotion_06" src="http://chitrchatr.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/Promotion_06.png" width="243" height="61" /></a>
 </div>
</div>
```

Javascript-

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays)
        {
        var exdate=new Date();
        exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
        var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
        document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;
        }

        function getCookie(c_name)
        {
        var c_value = document.cookie;
        var c_start = c_value.indexOf(" " + c_name + "=");
        if (c_start == -1)
          {
          c_start = c_value.indexOf(c_name + "=");
          }
        if (c_start == -1)
          {
          c_value = null;
          }
        else
          {
          c_start = c_value.indexOf("=", c_start) + 1;
          var c_end = c_value.indexOf(";", c_start);
          if (c_end == -1)
          {
        c_end = c_value.length;
        }
        c_value = unescape(c_value.substring(c_start,c_end));
        }
        return c_value;
        }


        if(getCookie('abc')=="def" && document.getElementById('popupBox'))
        document.getElementById('popupBox').style.display='none';
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add path to your cookie

```
function setCookie(name, value, days, secure) {
  var expires = '';
  if (days) {
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
    expires = '; expires='+date.toGMTString();
  }
  var domain = locDomain;
  document.cookie = name + '='+escape(value) + expires + '; path=/' + (domain ? '; domain=.' + domain : '') + ((secure && locProtocol == 'https:') ? '; secure' : '');
}
```

Comment: Yes, that is the problem. How can i store cookie on root? Sorry i don't have much knowledge. After applying your code cookie store on same path(page's path) not in root, so popup appears again on different page.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the location of cookie as '/'

Comment: Yes, that is the problem. How can i store cookie on root? Sorry i don't have much knowledge.

Comment: The above post by vlad is good. Just make this change. Replace path=/;" by path/"