# How to set a cookie in such a way that it is accessible from other pages?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, cookies

I am using jQuery to set cookie value from one page and able to access it only from that page. From other pages the retrieved value of the cookie always shows up as null.

```
$.cookie('servedAddress', JSON.stringify(cookieObject))

$.cookie('servedAddress') // returns the cookie only from the page where it was initially set.
```

Comment: Check the `path` you're putting on the cookie

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, I went through this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21367312/javascript-cookie-doesnt-work-on-all-page and set the path as '/' but it didn't work.

Comment: In which case we can't really help you without seeing more of the context your code is running under. Given the two lines you've shown, there's no reason this would not be working